# how to put if condition in python bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

when I am scraping content from a web site some links dot have HTTP in the src tag for that I added this code

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<div class="answer-given-body ugc-base">
  <p><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F61d%2F61d6042d-e4dd-41d9-9a5c-0ceb481ddbc9%2FphpKFGb9B.png"/><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fd72%2Fd72dfa6c-8e50-475a-86cf-678a04ae4606%2FphpQZYPYo.png"/><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F4c7%2F4c775a01-8590-4b93-bc20-03d282586f95%2FphpE7XFWI.png"/></p>
  </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Select all the `img` tags
for tag in soup.select(".answer-given-body.ugc-base img"):
    tag["src"] = "https:" + tag["src"]

print(soup.prettify())
```

but some links have HTTP: in src then this code also adding HTTP again to that link see this :

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<div class="answer-given-body ugc-base">
  <p><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F61d%2F61d6042d-e4dd-41d9-9a5c-0ceb481ddbc9%2FphpKFGb9B.png"/><img alt="" src="https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fd72%2Fd72dfa6c-8e50-475a-86cf-678a04ae4606%2FphpQZYPYo.png"/><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F4c7%2F4c775a01-8590-4b93-bc20-03d282586f95%2FphpE7XFWI.png"/></p>
  </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Select all the `img` tags
for tag in soup.select(".answer-given-body.ugc-base img"):
    tag["src"] = "https:" + tag["src"]

print(soup.prettify())
```

so I need to put if condition there but I don't know how to add please help me Thanks before

Comment: `if 'http' in string:` would this work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a solution built into BeautifulSoup but you could simply condition on the URL you find.

One other place you might need to be careful of is locally referenced images, which start with either a `/` or simply just have their name 'image.png' as the src. You'll need to append the source URL of the page in these cases.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<div class="answer-given-body ugc-base">
  <p><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F61d%2F61d6042d-e4dd-41d9-9a5c-0ceb481ddbc9%2FphpKFGb9B.png"/><img alt="" src="https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fd72%2Fd72dfa6c-8e50-475a-86cf-678a04ae4606%2FphpQZYPYo.png"/><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F4c7%2F4c775a01-8590-4b93-bc20-03d282586f95%2FphpE7XFWI.png"/></p>
  </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Select all the `img` tags
for tag in soup.select(".answer-given-body.ugc-base img"):
    tag["src"] = tag["src"] if tag["src"].startswith("http") else "https:" + tag["src"]

print(soup.prettify())
```

One advisable way to handle the sources is to use the urllib.parse function:
`from urllib.parse import urlparse` as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) it breaks the url into it's components which you can then use to re-add those components for requesting:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('//www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='www.cwi.nl:80', path='/%7Eguido/Python.html',
            params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('www.cwi.nl/%7Eguido/Python.html')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='www.cwi.nl/%7Eguido/Python.html',
            params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('help/Python.html')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='help/Python.html', params='',
            query='', fragment='')
```